# Best approach to migrate shared folders and not break links to files

Tags: windows, network-share, network-attached-storage

We are going to migrate some shared folders from our windows servers to a NAS appliance that we already have. What is a good way to maintain links inside the files located in these shares?

There are lots of Excel, Word, etc. files that have links to other files and we don't want to break them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way would be to create DNS A records pointing to NAS with proper Windows server names, but you would have to rename the hostnames on the Windows servers or decommission if they are no longer used.

This also depends on NAS folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Untested and maybe not elegant, but it might be possible to create links back from the windows machine to the nas box.  for example \windowsbox\users\myUserName -> \nasbox\userdata\users\MyUserName so that when a user clicks on the link in the word doc, it attempts to open its previous location but is redirected (via the link) to the new location?

The windows CLI command "mklink" would probably be a good place to start.

It's not elegant in that it will still rely on the old windows server still being available and the links will need to exists.  It could buy you enough time to go through the docs and update the links though.